# jFreeChart: Change Bar color regardless of series

Tags: jfreechart

I need to change the color of Bars regardless of their series. so `setSeriesPaint()` is not useful in this case. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) method to return the desired color, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006785).