# JasperReports chart configuration

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I need to generate a chart like this sample :
[image: chart sample]

In this sample values are corrects but I must change to details :

1) On the value axis, I want to hide any not integer values (1.75, 1.25 ...)
2) I want each category of category axis to be in a different color.

Is there a way to configure my JasperReports so it will behave as I expect it will ?

Comment: I'm curious to know if any of the suggestions solved the issue. Is it working as desired now?

Answer (score 4):

1. Invoke [`setTickUnit()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setTickUnit%28org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit%29) on the range axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853145/jfreechart-and-y-axis-units/7853498#7853498).
2. Override [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336010/jfreechart-change-bar-color-regardless-of-series/3336838#3336838).

Comment: Well I really think it works when your generates your reports with the help of java code. But in my case I can only use jrxml files generated with iReport and sadly it does not feat :(

Comment: Is [`ChartCustomizer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770045/customizing-dates-on-the-gantt-chart-for-jasper-reports/7771293#7771293) available to you?

Comment: Yes, setTickUnit() is relevant... but really createIntegerTickUnits() is more precisely what Manuel needs in this case.

Answer (score 4):

1) In iReport you can set the Minimum Tick Interval. Set that to "1", and you might get exactly what you need without any coding. It would work in the example you have posted. But it won't work in all cases. For example, you could still get a chart with tick marks at 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10. Start with this idea before looking into chart customizers.

1b) You need a chart customizer or a chart theme to be certain the axis is exactly what you want in all cases. I **really** hate those non-integer tick marks too! You could use the [chart customizer here](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/) to solve it. That would give you the desired result with no further Java coding needed.

2) Conceptually you have 1 series plotted on 3 categories in your example. You could swap this and plot 3 series in a single category. You might call the category "" or "dummy" but not display it. Results:

- 3 differently colored bars. (hooray!)
- Category descriptions are gone. (boo!)
- Legend could replace the category descriptions. (good enough?)

2b) Of course you could use a chart customizer to get precisely what you want... but the extra effort might be too much (or indeed, impossible if you don't have a Java background).