# How to set Jfree GanttChart Subtasks Color and labels

Tags: jfreechart

I am using the Jfree Charts to display Gantt Chart.I have to display differnt colors to the subtasks that are present under one series.

For Example if I have 5 tasks in series One: each task should have different color 
Also,I need to print label for each task .

I tried many ways but not successful and could only set the series color alone.

Please can any one help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to override [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) in your subclass of `GanttRenderer`. Just return a different color for each `column`.

Addendum:

> I would need to paint the subtask depending on the task completed or not irrespective of the column value.

If I understand, you would return the completed color if that column was completed; otherwise return the non-completed color.

> However, please can [you] send a code snippet.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006785) should help you see the relationship between row/column and series/item.

> Also, could you please let me know how to print the labels on the subtasks.

Because, a `GanttRenderer` is an `IntervalBarRenderer`, I'd look at  a [IntervalCategoryItemLabelGenerator](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/IntervalCategoryItemLabelGenerator.html).

> It's not really working.

What's not working? You haven't posted any code. The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006785) cited is a modification to the standard [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html); it produces the following output. Note in particular how there are three series (parameter `row`), each having five values (parameter `col`). The `super` implementation of `getItemPaint()` simply returns the series paints in a cycle. Your would override that behavior to do whatever your application requires.

```
0 0 java.awt.GradientPaint@7e1a9d1b
1 0 java.awt.GradientPaint@540984b
2 0 java.awt.GradientPaint@53ce669e
0 1 java.awt.GradientPaint@7e1a9d1b
1 1 java.awt.GradientPaint@540984b
2 1 java.awt.GradientPaint@53ce669e
0 2 java.awt.GradientPaint@7e1a9d1b
1 2 java.awt.GradientPaint@540984b
2 2 java.awt.GradientPaint@53ce669e
0 3 java.awt.GradientPaint@7e1a9d1b
1 3 java.awt.GradientPaint@540984b
2 3 java.awt.GradientPaint@53ce669e
0 4 java.awt.GradientPaint@7e1a9d1b
1 4 java.awt.GradientPaint@540984b
2 4 java.awt.GradientPaint@53ce669e
```

Comment: Hi,

I would need to paint the subtask depending on the task completed or not irrespective of the column value..@trashgold

However,please can u send code snippet.

Also,could you please let me know how to print the labels on the ubstasks.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi I tried using it but not successful with the code I have.Can u please send me a basic example code showing with few subtasks labels on the Gantt Bars.

Comment: @Med: the example I cited above is a straightforward extension to a category demo that comes with `JFreeChart`. You can start with it to construct an sscce that clarifies your problem http://sscce.org/