# Adding points to XYSeries dynamically with JfreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am facing problems in adding points to XYSeries. I have two classes. One is `Sample` (it has a `main` method) and the other class is `JfreeChart` (it has `JfreeChart` Code). In my `Sample` class I have a 2D array `sample[row][2]` which has initially 10 rows, and then I need to call the `JfreeChart` class and add them to XYSeries and display a scatter plot. I managed to do this, but the next time I call the `Jfreechart` class my Array has 25 rows.

I need to add the values to XYSeries and plot them on a scatter plot which should display the earlier 10 rows' values with different colors and now 25 rows values with different colors… and this goes on. Can anyone give some suggestions or examples?

```
class Sample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("(X,Y) Paired Values");
        double[][] sample = new double[row][2];

        for (int g = 0; g < sampe.length; g++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < 2; h++) {
                System.out.print("" + sample[g][h] + ",");
            }
        }
        JfreeChart sample = new JfreeChart("Demo", sample);
    }

    static XYDataset samplexydataset2(double[][] sample) {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("DataSet");
        for (int x = 0; x < sample.length; x++) {
            series.add(sample[x][0], sample[x][1]);
        }
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }
}
```

1)When I call "First Time" JfreeChart Class I will be having these Pairs in my Sample Array

(0.78,0.80)
(0.21,0.19)
(0.181,0.187)

2)When I call JfreeChart Class "Second time" I will having Diffrent values in my Sample Array
(0.20,0.19)
(0.8,0.79)
(0.41,0.45)
(0.77,0.79)
(0.54,0.65)

And this goes for few times(10 times)So I need add this to "XYSeries" and "XYSeriesCollection" and display the "First time" Values and "Second time" Values when I call Second time JFreeChart Class

Comment: I want to draw a line chart in the same manner.Instead of this scattered points i have to use line chart.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add new values to the [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) using one of the available `add()` methods, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series). If you're getting adventitious rows, you'll need to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Addendum: Looking more closely at the (recently updated) [genesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart/7073428#7073428) of your example, some confusion is understandable: no array is needed at all. The example below includes a button that adds new samples to a second series.

> Can I change the Color of Points when I click the "Add" Button?

Each new series is a new color, as shown in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo). To change individual colors, the recommended way is to override the renderer's `getItemPaint()` method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003373/how-to-set-different-colors-to-the-bars-in-stacked-bar-chart-in-ireport/3006785#3006785).

[image: ScatterAdd]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208657
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057
 */
public class ScatterAdd extends JFrame {

    private static final int N = 8;
    private static final String title = "Scatter Add Demo";
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private XYSeries added = new XYSeries("Added");

    public ScatterAdd(String s) {
        super(s);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    added.add(rand.nextGaussian(), rand.nextGaussian());
                }
            }
        }));
        this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random");
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            double x = rand.nextGaussian();
            double y = rand.nextGaussian();
            series.add(x, y);
        }
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(added);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScatterAdd demo = new ScatterAdd(title);
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have gone through the Examples,but I could't understand much as I am Beginner.In my problem I am Using XYSeriesCollection & XYSeries since my Values are Paired Values(X,Y) and i need to plot them on Scatter Plot and how can I use TimeSeriesColelction with above? I will post the Code..please help me regarding these

Comment: Thanks Very Much! It helped me alot.                                                                                                           One Small Question again Can I change the Color of Points when I click the "Add" Button so that I can differentiate from the previous points...small example please if u dont mind..:)

Comment: It's not hard to do, but you'll want to experiment. More above.

Comment: Hi can you check this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552270/displaying-all-xyseries-at-once-in-jfreechart-for-improving-speed