# How to plot jfree line chart with real numbers in X and Y axis

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, linechart

I have to plot a line chart with the range of X and Y axis is in real numbers(eg.-n to n which are float values).How can i manually set the values.And this should be the dynamic chart.Actually im getting the data from the serial port frequently.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Revised to reflect XY requirement.*

Using [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart), here's a basic [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) of [`ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYLineChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) that demonstrates adding and removing [`XYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html)s. As you want to add *XY* pairs individually, create the chart with an [`XYSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html) consisting of one or more [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html). Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742/adding-points-to-xyseries-dynamically-with-jfreechart/7208723#7208723) that adds data dynamically to a scatter plot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Im working with this only but how can i plot the X and Y axis values as per my requirements i.e both x and y axis values are in float(-n to n).And in the time series charts X axis is having date values,but i need it to be in float.

Comment: Ah, I incorrectly assumed a time domain; I've suggested an alternate approach above.