# Displaying string-Double in form of bar chart in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I want to display certain values in form of bar-chart.Following is the dataset which i am having

```
List<Double> centralityList = (List<Double>) request
            .getAttribute("centralityList");

List<String> labelList = (List<String>) request
            .getAttribute("labelList");
```

These values i am fetching from servlet to jsp and finally in jsp i want to display label list as x-axis and centrality list as
y-axis .That is the corresponding centrality value of each label stored in the following list respectively to be displayed in Bar chart format.

what to give in dataset?

I was trying with jfreeChart but somedatasets take double value as parameters

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JFreechart does not support X and Y coordinates in separate lists because forming a point on a 2-D chart requires a pair of X and Y coordinates. You may use XYSeriesCollection as explained in [Adding points to XYSeries dynamically with JfreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742/adding-points-to-xyseries-dynamically-with-jfreechart). I hope that helps.