# Displaying all XYSeries at once in jFreeChart for improving speed

Tags: java, jfreechart

Suppose that we need to display multiple `XYSeries` in a single `XYSeriesCollection`. My problem is that every time I add a `XYSeries`, the `JFreeChart` wants to update the chart and that slows down the process of displaying multiple `XYSeries`.

What I want is similar to this:

```
// Do not update the chart
XYSeriesCollection.add(XYSeries1)
XYSeriesCollection.add(XYSeries2) 
...
XYSeriesCollection.add(XYSeries10)
// Update the chart
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new `XYSeriesCollection` having the desired series, and invoke `setDataset()` on the `XYPlot`. This will generate  a single `DatasetChangeEvent`.

Addendum: Here's an SSCCE that updates *N* series, each having *N<sup>2</sup>* values. As this is a performance question, the example may be helpful in [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513).

[image: test image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Day;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

public class ChartPanelTest {

    private static final int N = 16;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeriesCollection tsc = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Data" + j);
            Day current = new Day();
            for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
                series.add(current, random.nextGaussian());
                current = (Day) current.next();
            }
            tsc.addSeries(series);
        }
        return tsc;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Test", "Day", "Value", dataset, false, false, false);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
                JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
                final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
                ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(600, 300);
                    }
                };
                f.add(chartPanel);
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("New") {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        plot.setDataset(createDataset());
                    }
                }));
                f.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please take a look at this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574733/how-to-make-jfreechart-displaying-the-tooltip-point-information-faster

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the documentation for `XYSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeriesCollection.html) (assuming `add` should be `addSeries`) there is no method `addAll` (or similar).

If you want, you *could* extend `XYSeriesCollection` and implement `addAll`. In this method, you could temporarily disable all listeners before adding and re-add them after. However, this would probably be a bad idea, and would definitely need to be `synchronized`:

- it would produce unpredictable polymorphism behavior
- it would require reflection hacks, as `AbstractDataset.listenerList` is `private`
- it could generate a security exception
- it would not be thread safe

So the short answer is **no, it is not feasible**.

---

… but this is a starting point for how you *could* do it:

```
Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("listenerList");
field.setAccessible(true);
EventListenerList ell = field.get(this);
// go from here
field.setAccessible(false);
```