# How to make jfreechart displaying the tooltip point information faster

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to make the point info tooltip appear faster. How can i do it? with the default setting I have to hover the mouse onto the point, then wait to be able to see point coordinate information. I want the point coordinates to be immediately available. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) provides `getInitialDelay()` and `setInitialDelay()` to query and alter "the initial tooltip delay value used inside this chart panel." As a concrete example based on [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java), the following change to the constructor eliminates the initial delay entirely:

```
public BarChartDemo1(String title) {
    super(title);
    …
    chartPanel.setInitialDelay(0);
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a late solution but here it is.
Here is how i handled with JavaFX.
It shows the tooltip fast instant and tooltip does not fade after a while.

```java
    /**
     * The "tooltip" is the hard-coded id for the tooltip object.
     * It's set inside the JFreeChart Lib.
     * */
    public static String TOOLTIP_ID = "tooltip";

    public static void removeTooltipHandler(ChartViewer chartViewer) {
        chartViewer.getCanvas().removeAuxiliaryMouseHandler(chartViewer.getCanvas().getMouseHandler(TOOLTIP_ID));
    }

    public static void addFasterTooltipHandler(ChartViewer chartViewer) {       
        if(chartViewer.getCanvas().getMouseHandler(TOOLTIP_ID) != null) {
            removeTooltipHandler(chartViewer);
        }
        chartViewer.getCanvas().addAuxiliaryMouseHandler(new TooltipHandlerFX(TOOLTIP_ID) {
            Tooltip tooltip;
            boolean isVisible = false;
            @Override
            public void handleMouseMoved(ChartCanvas canvas, MouseEvent e) {
                if (!canvas.isTooltipEnabled()) {
                    return;
                }
                String text = getTooltipText(canvas, e.getX(), e.getY());
                setTooltip(canvas, text, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            }
            
            private String getTooltipText(ChartCanvas canvas, double x, double y) {
                ChartRenderingInfo info = canvas.getRenderingInfo();
                if (info == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                EntityCollection entities = info.getEntityCollection();
                if (entities == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                ChartEntity entity = entities.getEntity(x, y);
                if (entity == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return entity.getToolTipText();
            }
            
            // This function is copied from Canvas.setTooltip and manipulated as needed.
            public void setTooltip(ChartCanvas canvas, String text, double x, double y) {
                if (text != null) {
                    if (this.tooltip == null) {
                        this.tooltip = new Tooltip(text);
                        this.tooltip.autoHideProperty().set(false); // Disable auto hide.
                        Tooltip.install(canvas, this.tooltip); 
                    } else {
                        this.tooltip.setText(text);           
                        this.tooltip.setAnchorX(x);
                        this.tooltip.setAnchorY(y);
                    }                  
                    this.tooltip.show(canvas, x, y);
                    isVisible = true;
                } else {
                    if(isVisible) {
                        this.tooltip.hide();
                        isVisible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```