# Update a XY line JFreeChart dinamically with different refresh rates

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm currently drawing a `JFreeChart` that I want to print with different "refresh rates". At the moment, I can print it with "one shot", however I haven't been able to print it dinamically. The refresh rate I have it as an `int` value saved in my code.

Before printing, I make all of the calculations and then print it. What I am trying to do now is print while calculating. As soon as I get the value of one point, print it, and so on.

My calculation code is as follows:

```
XYLineChart_AWT chartTemp = new XYLineChart_AWT();
int refreshRate = getRefreshRate();
for (int i = 0; i<MaxValue;i++) {
   //calculate values of Array1, Array2 and Array3
   chart1.setChart(chartTemp.runSimGraph("Title", "XLabel", "YLabel",true, new double[][]{Array1,Array2,Array3}));
}
```

However, this does only prints the `JFreeChart` at the end of the `for`-loop (tried it with Thread.sleep() method before the ending of each `for` iteration).

How may I be able to print the graph dinamically? Do I need to update the dataset as I calculate the values? If so, how can I do that?

EDIT: I've created a small verifiable example of what I want to fulfill. If I press the button, instead of the chart showing up as the calculations are made, it just shows up when it is finished. I want a way for it to show up point by point after its calculation. And yes, calling setChart() every iteration is wildly unefficient.

Code:
Test1.java

```
 package cenas;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Test1 extends JFrame 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private JTabbedPane tabbedBackground;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test2 secondFrame = new Test2();
                    Test1 mainFrame = new Test1(secondFrame);
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                    secondFrame.setVisible(true);
                    secondFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // given some values of w & h
        return new Dimension(1000, 650);
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Test1(Test2 secondFrame) {

        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setTitle("IMESS Simulator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 650));


        tabbedBackground = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        setContentPane(tabbedBackground);
        initComponentsandRunSimulator(secondFrame);
        pack();
        //setResizable(false);

    }

    private void initComponentsandRunSimulator(Test2 frame2) {


        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedBackground.addTab("Strategy and Results", null, panel1, null);
        tabbedBackground.setEnabledAt(0,true);
        panel1.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[400.00px,grow]20[300px,grow]20[300.00px,grow]", "[40px,grow 20][][][][][100px,grow]20[20px]20[250.00px,grow]"));


        JButton myButton = new JButton("Button - Press me");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame2.setComponentsLists(100);
            }
        });

        //Add Simulation Panel to the layout
        panel1.add(myButton, "cell 1 1 2 5,grow");
    }

}
```

Test2.java

```
package cenas;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;


import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Test2 extends JFrame{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedBackground2;
    private ChartPanel chart1 = new ChartPanel (null);
    private int value;



    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // given some values of w & h
        return new Dimension(1000, 650);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test2 frame = new Test2();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setComponentsLists(int refreshRate) {
        this.value=refreshRate;
        System.out.println("ola");
        simulateValues(refreshRate);
    }

    public Test2()  {
        setTitle("IMESS Simulator - Decision System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 650));

        tabbedBackground2 = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        setContentPane(tabbedBackground2);
        initComponents();
        pack();
    }

private void initComponents() {

        // Panel
        JPanel panelSimulation = new JPanel();
        tabbedBackground2.addTab("Strategy and Results", null, panelSimulation, null);
        tabbedBackground2.setEnabledAt(0,true);
        panelSimulation.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[400.00px,grow]20[300px,grow]20[300.00px,grow]", "[40px,grow 20][][][][][100px,grow]20[20px]20[250.00px,grow]"));

        chart1.setPopupMenu(null);
        chart1.setVisible(true);

        //Add Simulation Panel to the layout
        panelSimulation.add(chart1, "cell 0 2");
    }

private void simulateValues(int sliderValue) {



    double[] Array1 = new double[1440];
    double[] Array2 = new double[1440];
    double[] Array3 = new double[1440];
    for(int i = 0; i<1440; i++) {
        Array1[i]=0;
        Array2[i]=0;
        Array3[i]=0;
    }

    int peaks = 0;



    GraphTest chartTemp = new GraphTest();


    //Simulation for 24h (1 point per minute)
    for(int i = 0; i<1440; i++) {
        //Some calculations 
        if(i!=0)
            Array1[i]=Array1[i-1];

        if (((i>5) && (i<300)) || ((i>400) && (i<700)))
        {
            //Increase the energy per minute
            if((Array1[i]+10)<=50)
                Array1[i] = Array1[i]+ 10;

            else { //if we charge at normal rate, it could surpass capacity, so there may be leftovers
                Array1[i]=27;

            }       

        }

        if (peaks==0) {
            //Check if there is enough energy to supply in the ESS
            if(Array1[i]>Array2[i]) {

                Array3[i]=Array2[i]; //usage by the ESS
                Array2[i]=0; //Visualization purposes - grid does not provide any energy
                Array1[i]=Array1[i] - Array3[i]; //energy used by ESS

            }

        }

        chart1.setChart(chartTemp.runSimGraph("Title", "xLabel", "yLabel", true, new double[][]{Array1,Array2,Array3}));
    }


}


}
```

GraphTest.java

```
package cenas;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation; 
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection; 
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;



public class GraphTest {


    public JFreeChart runSimGraph(String chartTitle, String xLabel, String yLabel, boolean legend ,double[][] graphValues) {


        JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            chartTitle,
            xLabel,
            yLabel,
            createSimDataset(graphValues),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            legend, false, false);
        final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot();

        //Axes (Domain - x , Range - y)
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setRange(0,24);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(false, true);
        //renderer.setBaseLinesVisible(false); // retira as linhas entre os pontos
        //renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(false); //apaga o centro das shapes
        //renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(false); //apaga as shapes
        Shape teste = new Rectangle2D.Double(-(1.2/2), -(1.2/2), 1.2, 1.2);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, teste);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        //renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
        renderer.setSeriesShape(1, teste);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(2, teste);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.GREEN);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);

        return xylineChart;
    }

    private XYDataset createSimDataset(double[][] values) {

        double[] gridAr=values[0];
        double[] essAr=values[1];
        double[] availableEnergy=values[2];

        final XYSeries temp1 = new XYSeries("1");
        final XYSeries temp2 = new XYSeries("2");
        final XYSeries temp3 = new XYSeries("3");


        for (double i = 0; i < 1440; i++) {
            temp1.add(i / 60, gridAr[(int) i]);
            temp2.add(i/60, essAr[(int)i]);
            temp3.add(i/60, availableEnergy[(int) i]);
        }
        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(temp1);
        dataset.addSeries(temp2);
        dataset.addSeries(temp3);
        return dataset;
    }




}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the "long post",

Nhekas

Comment: `My calculattion code is as follows:` Where is this 'calculation' code being called? In other words, what context? Is this in its own thread? On the EDT?

Comment: @copeg you're right, It is not a complete explanation.
I have a main .java class that is a Jframe with various components. When I press a specific button the calculations begin. Therefore, that `for` loop is called inside a Jbutton's `ActionListener`.

Comment: `That for loop is called inside a button.` Do you mean inside an ActionListener of the JButton?

Comment: Yes, it is inside an ActionListener of a Jbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is single threaded - painting and events occur on the Event dispatch thread (EDT). From your comment above, the loop you posted is called within an `ActionListener` - which occurs on the EDT, so changes to the UI (eg changes in charts) will not occur until the EDT is free to repaint (eg sometime after the `actionPerformed` method ends).

> what I want to print with different "refresh rates"

**If you want to refresh the entire chart at a given rate**, I would recommend using a `javax.swing.Timer`, updating the chart as necessary. For example, to fire the timer from the ActionListener of a JButton at a rate of once per second:

```
ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //create the arrays
                chart1.setChart(chartTemp.runSimGraph("Title", "XLabel", "YLabel",true, new double[][]{Array1,Array2,Array3}));
            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }
};
myButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

**If you want to refresh a chart with points as they become available**, consider a) performing your calculations in its own thread and then b) add the points to the XYSeries (on the EDT - this is as opposed to recreating the dataset every time). An example, adapted from [Adding points to XYSeries dynamically with JfreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742/adding-points-to-xyseries-dynamically-with-jfreechart) :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;


public class DynamicPlotAddition extends JFrame {

    private static final String title = "Dynamic Point Addition";
    private final Random rand = new Random();
    private XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Added");

    public DynamicPlotAddition(String s) {
        super(s);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Runnable runner = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int total = 1000;
                int iter = 0;
                while ( iter++ < total ){
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            series.add(rand.nextGaussian(), rand.nextGaussian());
                        }

                    });

                    try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }

        };
        new Thread(runner).start();
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "X", "Y", createDataset(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DynamicPlotAddition demo = new DynamicPlotAddition(title);
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the example posted, you make the call to `simulateValues` from a new thread, and as each point pair is generated update the appropriate series

Comment: The updates to the chart should be done on the EWT, So either use a SwingWorker instead of Timer, or wrap the setChart() call inside a SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: @copeg Thanks, but that solution didn't work, because  if I put that timer within the loop, It only   performs the actionPerformed method after it finishes.
 And I want for it to update the chart each iteration.

Comment: @FredK Its a Swing timer....From [How to use...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) `Swing timer's task is performed in the event dispatch thread`

Comment: @FredK how can I accomplish your suggestion? Could you make an example, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nhekas Don't place it in a loop. You should start the timer once and it will fire the ActionListener for every iteration until it is told to stop.

Comment: @copeg I did what you said. Started the timer before the loop and stopped after it. It never called the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: @Nhekas, why are you stopping the Timer? And why still looping? Just start the timer. See updated code

Comment: @copeg the looping is required to calculate the values of the 3 arrays. And I've tried as you specified. The setChart() method does not draw the graph until it is  completely finished, I don't know why. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116007/discussion-between-copeg-and-nhekas).

Comment: @trashgod I checked that example and it worked, it started to input values dinamically. However, I want to calculate the values, then send them to the graph like shown in `Test2.java` . How can I send the values to `GraphTest.java` after the calculation and only then update the graph series? Thanks in advance

Comment: @trashgod I haven't completely understood this last question/answer. However, I will try to implement it and see the result.

Comment: @trashgod I was able to use the swing worker to insert values on the graph in one series. However, how can I send multiple values for multiple series with the `publish()` method?

Comment: @copeg Thanks for the edit. You and trashgod explained and detailed well your answers! I was finally able to do it. Thanks!