# Setting Different Color to particular Row in Series-JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have array of elements and they belong to one Series,with these elements I calculated Centroids. Problem is when I display them with "ScatterPlot" I need to show "Array Elements" with  "One Color" and the Centroid of these points in "Different Color".

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DefaultDrawingSupplier;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

public class Scatteradd extends JFrame {

    int i, x = 0, n1 = 0;

    public Scatteradd(String title, final double[][] samples) {
        super(title);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final DefaultXYDataset dataset = new DefaultXYDataset();
        dataset.addSeries("Series0", createSeries(0, samples));
        //dataset.addSeries("Series1", createSeries(1,trainingset3));
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Series");

        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int n = dataset.getSeriesCount();
                System.out.println("N-SIZE" + n);
                dataset.addSeries("Series" + n, createSeries(n, samples));
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        JButton remButton = new JButton("Remove Series");
        buttonPanel.add(remButton);
        remButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int n = dataset.getSeriesCount() - 1;
                dataset.removeSeries("Series" + n);
            }
        });
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    /**
     * Create a series
     * @param samples 
     * 
     * @ return the series
     */
    private double[][] createSeries(int mean, double[][] samples) {

        double[][] series = new double[2][samples.length + 1];

        System.out.println("SSSKSKSValue" + series.length);
        double p = 0, q = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {

            series[0][i] = samples[i][0];
            p = p + samples[i][0];
            series[1][i] = samples[i][1];
            q = q + samples[i][1];
            //System.out.println("Series Values"+series[0][i]+","+series[1][i]);
        }


        series[0][samples.length] = p / samples.length;//Centroid Calculation
        series[1][samples.length] = q / samples.length;//Centroid Calculation
        //Printing All Points in Series Array and the Last Row is the Centroid Values
        //which I want display in different Color on Scatter Plot
        for (int v = 0; v < series[0].length; v++) {
            System.out.println("Series Values" + series[0][v] + "," + series[1][v]);
        }

        return series;

    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

        // create the chart...
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "Scatter Plot Demo", "X", "Y", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

        // set chart background
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        // set a few custom plot features
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        Shape[] cross = DefaultDrawingSupplier.createStandardSeriesShapes();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xffffe0));
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = (XYItemRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, cross[0]);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);

        return chart;
    }

    /** Main method **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] trainingset3 = {
            {0.428053, 0.409742,},
            {0.415487, 0.401414,},
            {0.404834, 0.400493,},};
        Scatteradd demo = new Scatteradd("JFreeChartDemo", trainingset3);

        demo.pack();
        demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        demo.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

```
SSSKSKSValue2
Series Values0.428053,0.409742
Series Values0.415487,0.401414
Series Values0.404834,0.400493
Series Values0.4161246666666667,0.403883
//Centroids of above 3 Rows
```

Is there any method to show particular row in a series with different Color,Any example provided regarding this would be great and helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override [`getItemPaint`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) in the scatter plot's `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` and choose your color based on any desired combination of `row` and `col`. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003373/how-to-set-different-colors-to-the-bars-in-stacked-bar-chart-in-ireport/3006785#3006785), although it's for a different renderer.

Addendum: The general idea appears in `MyRenderer`, which `extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer`.

[image: Scatter plot custom renderer image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DefaultDrawingSupplier;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

public class ScatterColors extends JFrame {

    private static final Color centroidColor = Color.blue;
    private int centroidColumn;

    public ScatterColors(String title, final double[][] samples) {
        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultXYDataset dataset = new DefaultXYDataset();
        dataset.addSeries("Series", createSeries(0, samples));
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private double[][] createSeries(int mean, double[][] samples) {
        centroidColumn = samples.length;
        double[][] series = new double[2][samples.length + 1];
        double p = 0, q = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
            series[0][i] = samples[i][0];
            p = p + samples[i][0];
            series[1][i] = samples[i][1];
            q = q + samples[i][1];
        }
        series[0][samples.length] = p / samples.length;
        series[1][samples.length] = q / samples.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(series[i]));
        }
        return series;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "Scatter Plot Demo", "X", "Y", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        Shape[] cross = DefaultDrawingSupplier.createStandardSeriesShapes();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xffffe0));
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
        MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer(false, true);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, cross[0]);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        return chart;
    }

    private class MyRenderer extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer {

        public MyRenderer(boolean lines, boolean shapes) {
            super(lines, shapes);
        }

        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
            if (col == centroidColumn) {
                return centroidColor;
            } else {
                return super.getItemPaint(row, col);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] trainingSet = {
            {0.428053, 0.409742,},
            {0.415487, 0.401414,},
            {0.404834, 0.400493,},
        };
        ScatterColors demo = new ScatterColors("JFreeChartDemo", trainingSet);
        demo.pack();
        demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @trashgod.I have gone through the Example you mentioned above and it has parameters as row and column but in my Example above My Centroid is Paired values(0.4161246,0.403883).which means row is 3 but Column is  0 and 1 ...How can I specify both column for a single row..Thanks

Comment: Sorry, note update about renderer. I'm not following about the data set; Can you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @trashgod.I added code please go through that..see if u can help me..:

Comment: After I fix the compilation errors, I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `createSeries()`.

Comment: I posted the Error Free Code with Out Put of program.Thanks

Comment: @trashgod.Thanks Very much fr your Effort.Its working.I have one more small question I want to make the "Color for Centroids Dynamic"..because if suppose i have "AddButton" and when i add another "Series" to JfreeChart i will be again having "Centroids" for "Series2" So i want to show "Series2 Centroids" in different Color bcz to differentiate Series1 centroid with Series2 Centroids.....Thanks Very Much.

Comment: I'd re-factor the data set into a separate class that knows each series' centroid and distinguishing colors. During rendering, the view (renderer) can ask the model (data set) for the data it needs inside `getItemPaint()`.