# Customize bar colors in XYJfree chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, bar-chart

how to paint different bars in different colors, I tried to use renderer, here is my sample code:

```
    public IntervalXYDataset createDataset() throws InterruptedException {
    parseFile();
    final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Analysis");

    int i=0;
    while(parsedArray[i]!=0)
        {

        series.add(xaxisArray[i], yaxisArray[i]);

        i++;
    }

    final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

     dataset.setIntervalWidth(0.15);//set width here

    return dataset;
}
```

and this is how I am drawing the graph:

```
public className (final String title) throws InterruptedException {
    super(title);
    IntervalXYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
     XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint( 0, Color.black);//0 works and paints all 40 bars in black, 1 and above fails. 
             // plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint( 1, Color.green);// this fails
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2000,1000));//(width,height) of display
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

}
```

---

I am able to set the width as I have commented in my program, however I now want to set the color for different bars, for example I want to get hold of bar in chart and draw red for array[0] and blue for [3] and orange for cell[17], can you please guide me on this. Thank you very much.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer
Create two series, and then add how many ever bars you want and set color for each series. using setSeriesPaint

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is the following:

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.yellow);
```

Replace 1 with the (zero-based) index of the bar whose color you would like to change.

Edit to respond to comment:

```
List<Color> myBarColors = .....

XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(i, myBarColors.get(i));
}
```

Edit 2: Misunderstood OPs problem, new solution in comments.

Comment: This is a straightforward approach; but `Color.yellow` is the fourth default color, so it fails for more than three series.

Comment: Hello, I tried doing this, it works for value '0' as in setSeriesPaint( 0, Color.yellow); but I have around 40 bars - this loops for 40 times:-(series.add(xaxisArray[i], yaxisArray[i]);) can you please help me fix this error. I want to set color for each bar. Thank you so much.

Comment: @helloMaga I don't know *exactly* what you're trying to do, but I updated my answer to show setting colors in a loop.

Comment: Hello Jordan, please see my question above, I have declared my problem.

Comment: @helloMaga Ok, I took another look at the original post. I think that you're using the wrong class for your dataset. I don't have anything in front of me to test this, but try using CatagoricalDataset or XYBarDataset. If you use those the setSeriesPaint() method should work for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible approach is to override the [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) method of `AbstractRenderer` in a custom [`XYBarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283902/setting-different-color-to-particular-row-in-series-jfreechart/7285922#7285922) for `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`.