# CategoryPlot from a JTable - JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have to implement an histogram using `JFreeChart` API. This histogram has to represent the datas of this JTable:

[image]

So I have a JTable with three columns: "thea", "type", "Number of occurrences". My histogram has two targets: the first is to count the number of occurrences of each thea field; the second is to mark with different colors the bars corresponding to `JTable` records with different types.

To implement my histogram I used a `DefaultCategoryDataset`:

```
private DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset(ArrayList<String>fieldsOccs) {

DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for(int i = 0; i<this.fieldsOccs.size() && i<end; i++) {
    String thea = fieldsOccs.get(i).getFieldName();
    String type = fieldsOccs.get(i).getType();
    int occurrences  = fieldsOccs.get(i).getOccurrences();

    dataset.setValue(occurrences, type, thea);
    }   

return dataset;
}
```

Anf then I create my chart using a `createChart` method:

```
private JFreeChart createChart(DefaultCategoryDataset dataset) {

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "",                                             
            "",                                             //X-axis title
            "",                                             //Y-axis title  
            dataset,                                        //dataset
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,                     //plot orientation
            true,                                           //show legends      
            true,                                           //use tooltips
            false                                           //generate URLs
            );

    return chart;

}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

As you can see in the picture it is not nice to see. The values on x axes are not formatted correctly.

How can I solve this rendering problem?

--edit

I have this problem just in case of more types in the JTable. For example if my JTable is:
[image]

and there is just String, the correspondig histogram is nice:
[image]

--edit1

What dou you think about `StackedBarChart3D`? I get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> My histogram has two targets:

1. You may get a more appealing result with `ChartFactory.createHistogram()` and a `SimpleHistogramDataset`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29283528/230513).
2. To get diverse colors, override the `getItemPaint()` method in a custom `XYBarRenderer`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422243/230513).

Comment: I have this problem just where there are more types in the JTable. I edited my question with some datails.

Comment: Maybe use a `Map<String, Paint>` as a color lookup table in your `getItemPaint()`?

Comment: I edited my question. What do you think about the use of a StackedBarChart3D to solve this problem?

Comment: I never tried; this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) uses translucent colors instead.