# Diplaying only Bin ranges on x axis in SimpleHistogramDataset

Tags: jfreechart

Following is a code to arrange 4 Bins in SimpleHistogramDataset.

```
public class SimpleHistogramDemo extends JFrame{

    private SimpleHistogramDataset dataset;

    public SimpleHistogramDemo(String title) {
        super(title);

        // create the dataset with appropriate bins and some initial data
        this.dataset = new SimpleHistogramDataset("Key");
        dataset.addBin(new SimpleHistogramBin(10, 15, true, false));
        dataset.addBin(new SimpleHistogramBin(15, 20, true, false));
        dataset.addBin(new SimpleHistogramBin(20, 25, true, false));
        dataset.addBin(new SimpleHistogramBin(25, 30, true, false));
        try{

        dataset.addObservations(new double[] {10,12,13,17,16,18,22,25,24,23,21});
        }catch(java.lang.RuntimeException rte){
            System.out.println("some value Out of bin");
        }

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram("", 
                "Covers Passed", "Count", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
                false, false, false);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainZeroBaselineVisible(false);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        plot.getRangeAxis().setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(panel);
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleHistogramDemo demo = new SimpleHistogramDemo(
                        "JFreeChart: SimpleHistogramDemo");
                demo.pack();
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This example displays all integer numbers from 9 to 30 on x axis ,whereas I want to display only Bin ranges on x axis in such a way that each bin can be identified by its lower and upper bounds,i.e. Bin 1 should start from 10 and end at 15 similarly Bin 2 starts from 15 and end at 20 and so on. Also range labels on the Y axis are not displaying. How to solve these 2 problems?

Comment: sorry trashgod this is not what i want. Can i alot different colors to different bins

Comment: Maybe override `getItemPaint()`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36552669/230513)?

Comment: Concerning this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41323410/230513), I'd look at using _alpha_ and/or _visibility_, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513), to clarify overlapping data.