# JfreeChart: Color change on Mouse click event

Tags: jfreechart

I am writing an application that uses **Jfreechart** to plot a simple bar chart, this chart needs to respond to mouse clicks from the user. I would like to change the color of the bar that is clicked on by the user. I know that the event will be a **ChartMouseEvent** that will be handled by the **ChartMouseListener** but I am a little confused about how to change the color of the **ChartEntity** once I have received it from the event.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the color of an individual bar by overriding the renderer's [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285922/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513) for other renderer's. Once you receive a `ChartEntity` of type `CategoryItemEntity`, you can determine which dataset, series, and bar was clicked. Then you can condition your custom renderer's to apply the desired color with the next `repaint()`.

Alternatively, display each series and color in a `JTable` and use `JColorChooser` to select colors, as shown in [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).