# Different color for different series in XYline chart JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have created XY line chart using JFreeChart, having two datasets, I want both the lines to be in different colors. I tried using following code-

```
  XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
  XYItemRenderer xyir = plot.getRenderer();
  xyir.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GREEN);
  plot.setDataset(0, xyDataset1);

  xyir.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.blue);
  plot.setDataset(1, xyDataset2);
```

Also I have tried using following code, where I am using different renderer (don't know whether this is correct way to do it)-

```
  XYPlot plot1 = chart.getXYPlot();
  XYPlot plot2 = chart.getXYPlot();

  XYItemRenderer xyir1 = plot1.getRenderer();
  xyir1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GREEN);
  plot1.setDataset(0, xyDataset1);

  XYItemRenderer xyir2 = plot2.getRenderer();
  xyir2.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.blue);
  plot2.setDataset(1, xyDataset2);
```

In both the cases its printing both the lines in blue color.
What's wrong?? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the solution, it works for me, using two different Renderer, earlier i was not doing it properly--

```
 XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
  plot.setDataset(0, xyDataset1);
  plot.setDataset(1, xyDataset2);
  XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer0 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(); 
  XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer1 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(); 
  plot.setRenderer(0, renderer0); 
  plot.setRenderer(1, renderer1); 
  plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red); 
  plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(1)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
```

Answer (score 3):

The approach shown works in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513), and a single renderer should be sufficient. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may help isolate the problem.

To control individual items, you can override `getItemPaint()`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285922/230513).

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `Series` paint to `null` in the renderer `setSeriesPaint(null);`

If you take a look at the source it first checks to see if the paint is `!null`, then uses the base color.

If `null` it uses the colors associated with the time serie from a lookup table.