# How to synchronize TimeSeries colour with Marker colour in JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

I am displaying several time series lines along with Markers on a JFreeChart plot. Different markers are related to different time series and I would like them to appear in the same colour. So how do I find out for a given TimeSeries what is colour is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`lookupSeriesPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#lookupSeriesPaint%28int%29) for a given series. See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006785/230513) that overrides `getItemPaint()`, which calls `lookupSeriesPaint()`.