# How to change color of particular sub-task in JFreeChart Gantt Chart?

Tags: colors, task, jfreechart, gantt-chart

I have a Gantt Chart with 5 tasks. Each task is divided into 3 sub-tasks. I need to define different color for each sub-task, e.g. Sub-task1: "light blue", Sub-task2: "blue", Sub-task3: "dark blue". I tried to google some examples, but I didn't find any full working example. Thanks.

Update#1:
I'm using IntervalCategoryDataset for the dataset.

```
IntervalCategoryDataset dataset = createDataset(data);

final Task t = new Task("Resource " + i, date(time11), date(time14));
t.addSubtask(new Task("Resource " + i, date(time11), date(time12)));
t.addSubtask(new Task("Resource " + i, date(time12), date(time13)));
t.addSubtask(new Task("Resource " + i, date(time13), date(time14)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the renderer's [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29) method, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006785/230513).

Addendum: As a Gnatt chart uses a `GanttRenderer`, you'd do something like this to see the existing colors. Just return your chosen color for a given row and column.

```
plot.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
...
private static class MyRenderer extends GanttRenderer {

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(row + " " + col + " " + super.getItemPaint(row, col));
        return super.getItemPaint(row, col);
    }
}
```

Comment: I read this topic, but I don't understand what shoul be the whole solution. I need some small and clear example.

Comment: I tried this code. But I don´t understand where the Colors of sub-tasks are defined? If I do only this, then all sub-tasks still have the same blue color.

Comment: Where do I need to use getHSBColor()? Inside the getItemPaint or where?

Comment: It looks like `getItemPaint()` receives the row and column, but you'll have to query the model to `getSubtaskCount()`. I'm seeing two passes, but you can override `drawItem()` to be sure.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with getSubtaskCount()? I would not like to use drawItem() as it's less flexible method.

Comment: A complete example is beyond the scope of SO. You can probably assume two passes as a start. It's your data model; just invoke `getSubtaskCount()` on the relevant `Task`. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows representative data and color selection may help.