# JFreeChart How to get data points displayed on a Time series chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I just want to get the data points on my chart to show up, how do I do this?  The plot shows up fine as a line plot but I want small markers for each individual data point.

JFreeChart portion of the app is:

```
    private XYDataset createDataset() {
    final TimeSeries inclinometerAngles = new TimeSeries(TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Add all data from the map to the dataset
    final Set<Date> keys = data.keySet();
    for (Date date : keys) {
        Record r = data.get(date);
        if (r.mcInclinometerAngle != null) {
            inclinometerAngles.add(new Second(date), r.mcInclinometerAngle);
        }
    }        

    final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(inclinometerAngles);
    return dataset;
}   

private void setupGraphics() {
    final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "Tracker Analysis", 
        "Date", 
        "Value",
        dataset, 
        true, 
        true, 
        false
    );

    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();

    final StandardXYToolTipGenerator g = new StandardXYToolTipGenerator(
        StandardXYToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_TOOL_TIP_FORMAT,
        new SimpleDateFormat(), new DecimalFormat("0.00")
    );
    renderer.setToolTipGenerator(g);
    renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true);
    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`JFreeChart.createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) uses an [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html), so start by making the shapes visible.

```
renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(true);
```

This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513) illustrates a few of the other methods that affect the appearance.

Comment: This method now requires 2 params. An `int` and a `boolean`. The `int` represents the serie, and the `boolean` is the flag. So the syntax now looks like `renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);`.