# JFreeChart with highlighted points

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart` to draw a graph. The code is

```
package com.daya;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class Two extends ApplicationFrame {

    public Two(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1200, 1100));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("SLMM");
        final XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("FSPM");
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Power Comparision");
        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("d:\\devs\\Result.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(strLine);
            }
            String message = buffer.toString();
            message = message.replaceAll(" ", "");
            String[] splitMessage = message.split("&&&");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitMessage.length; i++) {
                double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
                String algType = "direct";
                String[] insideSplit = splitMessage[i].split("\\|\\|");
                if (insideSplit[0].equalsIgnoreCase("isStraightAlg:false")) {
                    algType = "indirect";
                }
                for (int j = 1; j < insideSplit.length; j++) {
                    String[] valueSplit = insideSplit[j].split("\\:");
                    if (valueSplit[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Transactions")) {
                        x = Double.parseDouble(valueSplit[1]);
                    } else {
                        y = Double.parseDouble(valueSplit[1]);
                    }
                    //System.out.println(valueSplit[1]);
                }

                if (!algType.equalsIgnoreCase("direct")) {
                    System.out.println("X :" + x + " Y:" + y);
                    series1.add(x, y);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("X :" + x + " Y:" + y);
                    series2.add(x, y);
                }
            }


            dataset.addSeries(series1);
            dataset.addSeries(series2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Power Comparison",
            "Transaction",
            "Energy",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        final XYPlot plot1 = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot1.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot1.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot1.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final XYPlot plot2 = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot2.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot2.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot2.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Two demo = new Two("Multi Line Chart");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and the text file is :

> isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 500 || Energy : 74267 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 500 || Energy : 55984 &&& isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 1000 || Energy : 169735 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 1000 || Energy : 162520 &&& isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 1500 || Energy : 333668 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 1500 || Energy : 313766 &&& isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 2000 || Energy : 494159 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 2000 || Energy : 481627 &&& isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 2500 || Energy : 594839 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 2500 || Energy : 594839 &&& isStraightAlg : false || Transactions : 3000 || Energy : 847096 &&& isStraightAlg : true || Transactions : 3000 || Energy : 842402 &&&

With the above code the graph is drawn. The graph is shown below. How can I show the exact points for what the graph is drawn, i.e selected `xy` point has to present with circle?

[image]

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart()` uses an `XYAreaRenderer`. The parent `AbstractRenderer` has methods to change the visibility and  appearance of shapes, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513) for the related `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`.

Addendum: Your complete example invokes `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`, which uses an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` internally. The image below resulted from adding these lines to `createChart()`:

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer =
    (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot1.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
```

[image]

Comment: i have jcommon.jar and jfreechart0.9.20.jar. i am facing compilation problem at renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);

Comment: Current is jfreechart 1.0.14 and jcommon 1.0.17.

Answer (score 2):

```
plot1.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);  // your existing code
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double shape = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(-2.0, -2.0, 4.0, 4.0);
plot1.getRenderer().setBaseShape(shape);
// or maybe plot1.getRenderer().setSeriesShape(0, shape);
```

Comment: i am new to the jfree. i am unable to understand where to change the code. I am college student.. So please give clear idea.. I am using it for my project

Comment: The chart returned by `ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart()` does not use a `LineAndShapeRenderer`, which is a `CategoryItemRenderer`.

Comment: chart.getPlot() should return XYPlot.

Comment: Sorry, chart.getPlot() should return XYPlot.  plot.getRenderer() should return XYItemRenderer, so you should be able to call setBaseShape (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYItemRenderer.html#setBaseShape(java.awt.Shape))

Comment: @NicholasAlbion i have updated my full code. Please check it and give me suggestions. I don't have any idea about JFree chart. For my academic project purpose i have started using..