# Draw Custom Lines using JFreeChart's XYLineAndShapeRenderer

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have some logic which I am using to construct a series of clusters. So far, to denote the cluster to which each point on the graph belongs to, I am using a series of colours, where points belonging to the same cluster are of the same colour.

Besides that, I would also like to display the centre of each cluster since this will help me see how my cluster building algorithm performs. To do this at the moment, I am writing some text on the graph through the use of the `XPointerAnnotation` class. The problem with this is that I think that having text on top of points can lead to a messy plot (considering that it is highly likely that there will be hundreds of points).

I thought of drawing lines going outwards, from the centre point to each of the members of its cluster. The problem I am facing is that I can't quite seem to find the correct method or methods which does that.

I have managed to find the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) of [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) and have tried to use it as a guide, but I still get no custom lines drawn on the plot. I have tried to override the `drawPrimaryLine`, `drawPrimaryLineAsPath` and `drawSecondaryPass` methods, but to no avail.

The code I am using to render the lines is as follows:

```
int x1 = (int) dataset.getXValue(series, 0);
int y1 = (int) dataset.getYValue(series, 0);

int x2 = (int) dataset.getXValue(series, item);
int y2 = (int) dataset.getYValue(series, item);

g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
System.out.println(String.format("Drawing %d  %d  %d  %d %s", x1, y1, x2, y2, g2.getColor()));

State s = (State) state;
if (item == s.getLastItemIndex()) {
    // draw path
    drawFirstPassShape(g2, pass, series, item, s.seriesPath);
}
```

The print statement prints the right coordinates and the right colours, so it just seems that the graphics that I am adding is not being rendered. I have tried calling `super`, both before and after my code is executed but to no avail either.

Any directions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: For convenience, the API uses `-linksource`, so you can click on any class name to see the source, for [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking more closely at the code posted, the *xy* value obtained from the `dataset` represents a point in *data* coordinates. Before such a point can be rendered, it must be transformed into *graphics* coordinates, relative to the `dataArea`. As an example, [`drawPrimaryLineAsPath()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#line.1063) uses the corresponding axis method, `valueToJava2D()`, to convert a data value to a graphics coordinate.

```
double transX1 = domainAxis.valueToJava2D(x1, dataArea, xAxisLocation);
double transY1 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(y1, dataArea, yAxisLocation);
```

Addendum: The [`drawPrimaryLineAsPath()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#line.1063) method is invoked from [`drawItem()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#line.887) only when `drawSeriesLineAsPath` is `true`, e.g. `setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however it now seems that the method is not being even called. I have uploaded my code [here](http://pastebin.com/CbTvqeAr) in the hopes that it sheds more light on the issue. I am simply initializing the renderer and then passing it to the xyPlot.

Comment: Are you calling `plot.setRenderer()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9843451/230513)?

Comment: Yes I am. I am passing it like so: `xyPlot.setRenderer(renderer);` and creating it like so: `ClusterRenderer renderer = new ClisterRenderer(clusters, true, true);`. I am able to get the points on the screen, so I think that the renderer is working, I just do not get the extra lines.

Comment: Did you `setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true)`?