# Pretty pie charts in JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to get complex, beautiful colors for pie charts in JFreechart? I mean how can I achieve the colors like the image shown in the [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Ml_wiki_photo_event_analysis_Pie_Chart_All_users.png)?

Is it possible using the RGB format, or do you need to use a different format? How can we do it. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the color using RGB values for each slice of the pie with [PiePlot.setSectionPaint](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setSectionPaint%28java.lang.Comparable,%20java.awt.Paint%29).

Here is an example :

```
  DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
  result.setValue("1", 40.);
  result.setValue("2", 30.);
  result.setValue("3", 20.);
  result.setValue("4", 10.);
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("", result, true, true, false);
  PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
  plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
  plot.setSectionPaint("1", new Color(31, 73, 125));
  plot.setSectionPaint("2", new Color(192, 80, 77));
  plot.setSectionPaint("3", new Color(155, 187, 89));
  plot.setSectionPaint("4", new Color(128, 100, 162));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setDrawingSupplier()` to supply a custom palette, as shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115314), or override `lookupSectionPaint()` to return any desired `Paint`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513) for `getItemPaint()`.

You'd have to experiment with the outline stroke to approximate the highlight.