# Changing series outline stroke and paint in scatter plot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a scatter plot created with `ChartFactory.createScatterPlot`. I would like to draw an outline around each point to get better visual feedback in regions with clustered points. I am trying it this way:

```
Shape cross  = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,5,5);
XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true)
XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesShape(0, cross);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.black);
renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2));
renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1));
```

But only the new shape is drawn, the points get no outline:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [factory method](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1663) cited instantiates [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html), so to see the change  you need to invoke [`setUseOutlinePaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#setUseOutlinePaint-boolean-), as well as `setSeriesOutlinePaint()` and (optionally) `setSeriesOutlineStroke()`.

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) xyPlot.getRenderer();
renderer.setUseOutlinePaint(true);
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.black);
renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2));
```

A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513).

Comment: I get this error message: "The method setUseOutlinePaint(boolean) is undefined for the type XYItemRenderer."