# Bubble chart with custom colors in each bubble in a series

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new to JFreeChart. I am trying to create a bubble chart that has a single series with up to 10 bubble, but I want to different color for each bubble.
I tried `xyitemrenderer.setSeriesFillPaint(0, Color.GREEN)`. But it giving only one color for all bubbles. How to setup multiple color for each bubbles in JFreeChart.

Comment: What happens with `setSeriesPaint()`?

Comment: Thanks, setSeriesPaint() giving only single color for all bubbles in a series, but I need custom color for each bubble in a series.

Answer (score 1):

> I need custom color for each bubble in a series.

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513), you can override the renderer's `getItemPaint()` implementation to return any desired color. The following example prints the default colors totes console.

```
JFreeChart chart = …;
XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYItemRenderer xyitemrenderer = new XYBubbleRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
        Paint p = super.getItemPaint(row, col);
        System.out.println(row + ", " + col + ": " + p);
        return p;
    }
};
xyplot.setRenderer(xyitemrenderer);
```