# How to use multiple TaskSeries in a JFreeChart TaskSeriesCollection

Tags: jfreechart, gantt-chart

If I put all my tasks into a single `TaskSeries`, I get normally sized Gantt chart bars, but when I take those same tasks, put them into multiple `TaskSeries`, it makes really skinny bars.  Is this a bug, or am I doing it wrong?

[image]
Right clicking and 'view image', you can read the code.

Comment: I am unable to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513) the effect you illustrate. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a solution but this may help you find one.

In your second example, `JFreeChart` is allowing space in each task (y axis) for each task series; the bar width is the available space / number of task series.
Hopefully this illustration helps:

[image]

In (A) I have created 6 tasks, but only one job; and in (B) I have created a second job and attached 3 Tasks to it.  In (B) the bars are roughly half as wide, so that there is space for both jobs in all tasks.  In (D) you can see that, as I have moved one of the tasks.
You can thicken the bars as mush as possible using this code:

```
  plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.05);
  plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.05);
  plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.05);
  GanttRenderer renderer = (GanttRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
  renderer.setItemMargin(0);
```

[This](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29782) thread on the `JFreeChart` board may shed some further light on the issue.