# Java Swing: Open source Gantt chart library

Tags: swing, charts, java, gantt-chart

I'm looking for a good open source Gantt chart library for Java Swing.
I tried JFreeChart but it is not able to draw subtask.
I tried with [SwiftGantt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftgantt/) too. It is able to draw subtask, but it is a little unstable and the look and feel is not professional :(.

Can you recomends others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at E-Gantt? http://egantt.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried it, but it is based on tables, but I did not find the way to create or configure nested subtasks.

Comment: Have you looked at JIDE Gantt Chart or JFreeChart or FlexGantt. http://www.jidesoft.com/products/gantt.htm http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html

Comment: See also this [`JFeeChart`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513).

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart provides Gantt Charts. Check out this  [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartGanttDemo1.htm)

Comment: if you dont understand or cant figure it out, just pop a comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer. JFreeCharts don't let create gantts with subtasks. The subtasks concept that JFreeCharts manage refers to tasks executed through several parts or fases. By example, Task 1 start at 1/1/2012 and stop at 1/31/2012, then restart at 3/1/2012 and stop a 4/15/2012, so and so

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely only a partial answer, but have you considered embedding a JavaFX chart in a JFXPanel? JavaFX has excellent chart making capabilities and is part of the standard Java 7 Runtime Environment. I believe that Gantt charts are, if not a built-in possibility, something that could be quickly implemented in a class.