# how to do partition of existing jfree pie Chart section on same chart

Tags: spring-mvc, jfreechart, pie-chart, jfreereport

I am using Jfreechart to create a pie chart in Spring MVC. 
MY requirement is:

`i have to create two section,FOUND and LOST on pie chart.also in,LOST section i need to create more sections representing Count of different LOST items. here`

right now,i am able to create  two sections on chart,FOUND and LOST.
but i am not getting how to do partition of LOST section on same chart. 
How can i achieve this..please help

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have started with [`org.jfree.chart.demo.PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html), as the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html) is include in the distribution. Unfortunately, `DefaultPieDataset` does not support sub-categories suitable for partitioning.

Here's an outline of one approach:

- Extend `DefaultPieDataset` to include the data required to model the partition, e.g. `Set<String> lost`and `Set<String> found`, representing the set of keys belonging to each partition.
- Use a palette or related colors to show related items, e.g. shades of red for `lost` and shades of blue for `found`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513) illustrates the approach for `GanttRenderer` using a palette of varying saturation. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513) illustrates the approach for `XYItemRenderer` using a palette of varying hue. Naturally, you'll need to override `getSectionPaint()` instead of `getItemPaint().`

[image]