# Partition pie chart into equal parts jfreechart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I have a data source in which there are three departments and each department has equal employees that are 8. 
I want to make a pie chart using jFreeChart such that first we partition the pie into 3 equal parts for departments that is 120' for each department. Then in these partitions I want to show the sales of each employee. How can I do this in jFreeChart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class PieChart extends JFrame {  

  private  PieDataset createDataset() {
            DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
            result.setValue("department1", 33.33);
            result.setValue("department2", 33.33);
            result.setValue("department3", 33.33);
            return result;

        }

     private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title,          // chart title
                dataset,                // data
                true,                   // include legend
                true,
                false);

            PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setStartAngle(290);
            plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
            plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
            return chart;

        }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
          PieChart demo = new PieChart("Comparison", "Which operating system are you using?");
          demo.pack();
          demo.setVisible(true);
      }
```

Comment: Its simple to create partitions but how to further create partitions in that? Thanks.

Comment: make paratition accordingly means pie chart usefull to partition so when you assigning any student then your 100% will be 33.33 as per department partition assign value below 33.33 and if you want to assign each 8 student equal then 33.33/8

Answer (score 2):

[`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html) is a good starting point; focus on `createDataset()`; the full [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html) is included in the distribution.

Addendum: *How to further create partitions?*

Ah, you want to sub-divide each 120° partition. `DefaultPieDataset` doesn't support a hierarchical structure directly, but you can use color in the `PiePlot` to highlight the grouping. Create related colors using `Color.getHSBColor()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513), and use `setSectionPaint()` to apply the colors accordingly.

Comment: Its simple to create partitions but how to further create partitions in that? Thanks.

Comment: I've suggested one approach above.