# Get different series to have the same color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I have two XYSeries that belong to a same dataset. First series has to show shapes only, while second series has to show lines only. Both must have the same color. Is there a way to do it ?

Providing the piece of code to better understand:

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("S1", false); // autosort disabled
    for(int i = 0; i < xValues.length; ++i)
        series.add(xValues[i], yValues[i]);

    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("S2", false);
    for(int i = 0; i < xValues.length; ++i)
        series1.add(yValues[i], xValues[i]);

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

    dataset.addSeries(series);

    dataset.addSeries(series1);

    // create a chart with title, axis labels, tooltips and maybe a legend
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(title, xLabel, yLabel, dataset, 
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, legend, true, false);

    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();

    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513), I edited the following lines to get the image below.

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) xyPlot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, true);
renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.blue);
```

Addendum: To get pairs of matching colors, you can override `getItemPaint()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285922/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916537/230513).

[image]

Comment: [Updated](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9763985/revisions) to use same color for both series.

Comment: Thanks. I omitted something, though. In my chart there can be lots of series,  each of them with two series. So each dataset has a single color, provided automatically by the library.

Comment: You can override `getItemPaint()`; I've linked to examples above.