# Change the Chart point color according to value - JFreeChart

Tags: java, csv, jfreechart, jfreereport

I have a CSV file which looks like this [(the file can be be downloaded here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lh7bb2gbenw2q8a/Electrical.csv?dl=0)
 [image]

I want to graph this with time (first column in the spreadsheet) on the X axis and the names of the switches on the Y axis (column headings for all but the first column). I expect to create one point on the Y axis for each column. The column will be horizontal to the X axis but the colors should change according to the values TRUE or FALSE, or 0, 1, 2.

This is what I've developed so far:

```
package democsv;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class DemoCSV extends ApplicationFrame {

    public static List<Object> sections = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String[] switchNames = null;
    public static ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> datastore = new ArrayList<>();

    public DemoCSV(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) throws IOException {
        super(applicationTitle);
        InputStream in = DemoCSV.class.getResourceAsStream("/files/Electrical.csv");
        InputStream in2 = DemoCSV.class.getResourceAsStream("/files/Electrical.csv");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
        String line, line2;
        int cnt = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataIn = line.split(",");

            if (cnt == 0) {
                switchNames = sNames(dataIn);
            } else if (cnt != 0) {
                time.add(dataIn[0]);
            }
            cnt++;
        }

        cnt = 0;

        int dsize = switchNames.length;

        while (datastore.size() < dsize) {
            datastore.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }


        while ((line2 = read.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataIn2 = line2.split(",");

            if (cnt != 0) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dsize; i++) {
                    datastore.get(i - 1).add(dataIn2[i]);
                }
            }
            cnt++;
        }

        for (String sn : switchNames) {
            sections.add(new XYSeries(sn));
        }

        JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                chartTitle,
                "Category",
                "Score",
                createDataset(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(xylineChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1366, 768));
        final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();

        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {


        ArrayList<Object> xystore = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String sn : switchNames) {
            xystore.add(new XYSeries(sn));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= switchNames.length; i++) {
            for (String x : time) {
                double y = Double.parseDouble(x);
                ((XYSeries)xystore.get(i-1)).add(y, i);
            }
        }

        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        for (Object xy : xystore) {
            dataset.addSeries((XYSeries)xy);
        }

        System.out.println(dataset);
        return dataset;

    }

    public static String[] sNames(String[] names) {
        String[] arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(names, 1, names.length);
        return arr;

    }

    public static void DataClear() throws IOException, NullPointerException {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DemoCSV test = new DemoCSV("Test", "second");

        test.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(test);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When this runs it generates something looking like this:

[image: graph]

I want to change the color of the points when the value in the column in the csv file changes (doesn't matter what the color is, it's the change in colour we want to see when we look at it). If that is not possible, a way to set value to each node would be enough (with a hover effect).

Comment: You can override `getItemPaint()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20XYLineAndShapeRenderer%20getitempaint).

Comment: Thank you Trashgod. This is what I'm searched for but now I'm stuck with returning color I want align to value of each series. I think my problem is I'm unable to find the code where color of node called. (when getItemFillPaint is called.) Can you point out where this called? Because I want to change color of node according to values in "datastore" arrayList. Here is my code so far. gist.github.com/Menuka5/e50c37fd7d4572c4966e

Comment: You can see the default value using the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3006785/230513). Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Robin Green for the answer but I used the method Trash god described.
To approach my goal I have to override `getItemPaint()` according to value of my `datastore`. I've posted it here because Trash god only commented it.

[How to set different colors to the bars in stacked bar chart in ireport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003373/how-to-set-different-colors-to-the-bars-in-stacked-bar-chart-in-ireport/3006785#3006785)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible to do this with an `XYPlot`. However, you could do it with a scatter plot (`FastScatterPlot`) instead. Instead of having the switches as series, make the values (TRUE, FALSE etc.) into series and keep the X and Y positions as they are now.

Also you should use [SymbolAxis](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html) for your Y axis. Call `setRangeAxis` on your `FastScatterPlot` to use the created `SymbolAxis`.

Comment: Can I know whether there is a example for your answer please?